# ^A & ^B characters when trying to configure log4cpp

Tags: android, android-ndk, configure, log4cpp

When I am trying to configure the log4cpp which is cloned from the location [Log4cpp CodeGit](http://sourceforge.net/p/log4cpp/codegit/ci/master/tree/).

I observe the ^A & ^B characters at the end of the #ifdef macros, due to which compilation is not going through.

Steps I followed are
1) git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/log4cpp/codegit log4cpp-codegit
2) ./autogen.sh
3) ./configure

Excerpt of Output file
include/log4cpp/config.h

```
* Define to 1 if you have the <dlfcn.h> header file. */
#ifndef LOG4CPP_^A 
#define LOG4CPP_^A ^B 
#endif

/* Define to 1 if you have the `ftime' function. */
#ifndef LOG4CPP_^A 
#define LOG4CPP_^A ^B 
#endif
```

Please let me know if anyone face this issue and resolved.

Thanks.

Comment: Found answer. Thought will be useful for others, if they face similar issue. So, not deleting the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, problem was in the wrong version of the autoconf which i was using.

Wrong version:

```
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69.117-1717-dirty
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>, <http://gnu.org/licenses/exceptions.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.
```

Current Version:

```
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>, <http://gnu.org/licenses/exceptions.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.
```